# Does WordPress clear $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

What I want to do is to include one of my PHP scripts in a Word Press theme. The problem is that after I include the script file I can't access, inside functions in the theme file, variables declared in the script file .

I have created a new file in the theme folder and added the same code as in header.php and if I open that file it works just fine. So as far as I can tell it's something Word Press related.

```
/other/path/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/header.php // this is broken
/other/path/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/test.php   // this works

/var/www/vhosts/domain/wordpress/ ->(symlink)-> /other/path/wordpress/
                                                /other/path/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/header.php
/var/www/vhosts/domain/include_file.php
```

Content of: /var/www/vhosts/domain/include_file.php

```
$global_var = 'global';
print_r($GLOBALS);  // if I open this file directly this prints globals WITH $global_var;
                    // if this file is included in header this prints all the WP stuff WITHOUT $global_var;
```

Content of: /other/path/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/header.php
    require '/path/to/include_file.php';

```
print $global_var; // this prints 'global' as expected
function test()
{
    global $global_var;
    print $global_var; // this is NULL
}
test();
print_r($GLOBALS); // this prints all the WP stuff WITHOUT $global_var in it
```

Comment: globals are bad practice, don't use it

Comment: I need to use it for a function that acts as an autoloader and receives it's parameter automatically. global was the simplest way to get data in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not promoting the use of `$GLOBALS`, but anyway... define your variable using:

```
$GLOBALS['varname'] = 'value';
```

That should work.  I suspect you're not actually in global scope like you think you are.  That file is probably being include by a function, in which case you're in function-scope.

Comment: I've just figured it out and returned to post the answer. But you are right i'm not in the right scope.

Thanks!