# Wordpress php page $GLOBALS problem

Tags: php, wordpress, include, global

Hi I've an issue while dealing with a php code inside Wordpress;

I've my aaa.php file wich contains code:

```
<?php
require_once("lang_file.php");
echo $GLOBALS['general']['username'];
?>
```

My lang_file.php contains:

```
<?php
$language['general']['username'] = 'User';
?>
```

And my Wordpress page contains this:

```
<?php
include("aaa.php");
?>
```

If i access directly aaa.php through browser i get the "User" message from the echo on aaa.php.

If i access the Wordpress page with include code it doesn't show nothing. I've already read this answer: [Does WordPress clear $GLOBALS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720783/does-wordpress-clear-globals)

And i tried to define the variables on lang_file.php as $GLOBALS but this still don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use

```
$GLOBALS['language']['general']['username']
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, `$GLOBALS` is an array of all variables defined globally. The first element of the array is the global variable name.

Therefore, to access the global variable `$language` via `$GLOBALS`, you would need to use `$GLOBALS['language']`. You can then append any array structure after that which you want to reference from `$language`.

You can also access it directly via the name `$language` if you prefer, by adding `global $language;` to the code prior to where you want to use it.